# Re-rendering a single row of a list without re-rendering the entire list

Tags: performance, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

we're trying to implement a contact list that works just like [the new Material Design Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/u/0/preview/all) (you must enable the material design skin to see it) using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui).
Specifically we're trying to show a checkbox instead of the avatar on row hover.
We'd like to catch and re-render only the interested row (when hovered) and show the avatar/checkbox accordingly... this seems an easy task but we're not able to isolate the render to the hovered row (instead of re-rendering the entire list)
Do you have any suggestion on how to do something like this?

Our temporary solution uses a container component that handles the table:
When a row is hovered we capture it from `onRowHover` of the `Table` component and save it in the container state. This triggers a re-render of the entire list with really poor perfomance.

You can see a video of the issue [here](http://sendvid.com/u303q921).

Here is a code sample:

```
import React from 'react'
import Avatar from 'material-ui/lib/avatar'
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/lib/checkbox'
import Table from 'material-ui/lib/table/table'
import TableHeaderColumn from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-header-column'
import TableRow from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-row'
import TableHeader from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-header'
import TableRowColumn from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-row-column'
import TableBody from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-body'
import R from 'ramda'

export default class ContactsList extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { hoveredRow: 0 }
    this.contacts = require('json!../../public/contacts.json').map((e) => e.user) // Our contact list array
  }

  _handleRowHover = (hoveredRow) => this.setState({ hoveredRow })

  _renderTableRow = ({ hovered, username, email, picture }) => {
    const checkBox = <Checkbox style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} />
    const avatar = <Avatar src={picture} />
    return (
      <TableRow key={username}>
        <TableRowColumn style={{ width: 24 }}>
          {hovered ? checkBox : avatar}
        </TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{username}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{email}</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
    )
  }

  render = () =>
    <Table
      height='800px'
      fixedHeader
      multiSelectable
      onRowHover={this._handleRowHover}
    >
      <TableHeader displaySelectAll enableSelectAll>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Nome</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn>Telefono</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} showRowHover>
        {this.contacts.map((contact, index) => this._renderTableRow({
          hovered: index === this.state.hoveredRow,
          ...contact }))
        }
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap your rows into a new component implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` like so :

```js
class ContactRow extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return this.props.hovered !== nextProps.hovered || ...; // check all props here
    }
    render() {
        const { username, email, ...otherProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <TableRow { ...otherProps } >
                <TableRowColumn style={{ width: 24 }}>
                    {this.props.hovered ? checkBox : avatar}
                </TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{this.props.username}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{this.props.email}</TableRowColumn>
             </TableRow>
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your `ContactList` component like so :

```
this.contacts.map((contact, index) => <ContactRow key={contact.username} {...contact} hovered={index === this.state.hoveredRow} />)
```

If you don't want to manually implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, you can use React's [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) or check a lib like [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) which provides useful helpers like `pure` to do so.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by the OP and @Denis, the approach above doesn't play well with some features of the `Table` component. Specifically, `TableBody` does some manipulation on its children's children. A better approach would be to define your `ContactRow` component like so:

```
class ContactRow extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        // do your custom checks here
        return true;
    }
    render() {
        const { username, email, ...otherProps } = this.props;
        return <TableRow { ...otherProps } />;
    }
}
```

and then to use it like this

```
<ContactRow { ...myProps }>
    <TableRowColumn>...</TableRowColumn>
</ContactRow>
```

But I guess having `TableRow` re-render only when necessary is a feature everyone would benefit from, so maybe a PR would be in order :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, we already tried this approach but it leads to another problem: TableRow and Table are strictly tied and need to be nested correctly to work.  Wrapping the TableRow with a React Component breaks many things (for example the hovering and selection of a tableRow won't be propagated correctly to the Table component).

Comment: @MatteoMazzarolo ok, i've edited my answer to take that into account. In this case, you need to pass back to TableRow any props that the TableBody component was passing it over.

Comment: thank you.
Passing the the TableBody props din't work correctly, it triggered a re-render of the entire list on row hover.
Unfortunately this is a time-sensible task so we're switching to another layout and I will investigate further in the next days.
I'm flagging your answer as correct anyway because I don't think there will be any better solution.  
I hope to be proved wrong though :)

Comment: thanks! I don't know material-ui, but i have the feeling there must be another issue, though, as this seems to work : https://gist.github.com/VonD/3c7d30ea39447de02ff968fcf416cd82 (only the desired ContactRow elements are re-rendered)

Comment: Have no idea why people upvoting this unswer, trick with ...otherProps doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Denis I can make an edit if something has changed. What is wrong with `...otherProps` ?

Comment: @VonD Oh I forgot to mentioned that problem described by Matteo Mazzarolo still exists and even passing props down doesn't help. In short - TableRow and Table and strictly tied, with additional node between them - many options doesn't work properly, for example rows selection(checkboxes)

Comment: @Denis I've edited the answer. hope that works for you.